# shortening url to cms

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

Hi
We have a CMS application that lets people create websites under our domain.
The system was built a few years ago and it used a method that transfers parameters such as website id, folder code and more using the url. this method created a giant url for every item in the website

For example:
My domain is www.domain.com
A users website on my domain is www.domain.com/user
and every time that a user enters his website he gets a link like this
www.domain.com/page.aspx?code=blablasdsdsdsdsds&folder=blablablablablabla and more.

We are trying to reduce the string size in the url.
What are our options? can we show the user one url like a virtual one and still work the same with the old url?
We are trying to locate a solution that wont make us rewrite our entire application.

the application is built in c# and the web server is iis 6.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are searching for URL rewriting.

For **IIS7** this functionality is build-in via the [URL Rewrite Module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx).

For **IIS6** you should read this MSDN article to follow the details on how to do it:

- [URL Rewriting in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx)

Or you could go with one of the numerous third-party tools to do it:

- [UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewrite](http://www.urlrewriting.net)
- [UrlRewriter.NET](http://urlrewriter.net/)
- [Ionics Isapi Rewrite Filter](http://iirf.codeplex.com/)
- [ISAPI_Rewrite](http://www.isapirewrite.com/)